# Symfony2 and Doctrine: how to use findOneBy method taking capitals into account

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

Using Symfony2, Doctrine and MySQL, I am using `findOneBy` method.

I need it to take capitals into account when talking about string criteria fields.

Example: imagine I have this `path` field in some table in my database.

```
id  path
---------
1   path1
2   path2
3   path3
4   path4
```

If I do `findOneByPath("PATH2")` it will find the second row.

The question: how can I make it to distinguish capitals, so that it wouldn't find any row in the described case?

Comment: maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/2710195/1370752

Comment: Thanks. I think that is Doctrine1. The one I use is 2. And I think that what I am facing is the opposite: I need my code to do DISCRIMINATE capital strings.

Comment: oh, you're right about doctrine, but you can see the sql code, anyway, I think you will have to write custom search, here are some examples that could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632598/how-to-search-for-exact-string-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not a doctrine/symfony issue - the problem is that your table collation is case-insensitive (this is the default), if you want searches to be case sensitive you need to use a different collation on your tables.

- [Doctrine and collation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#how-do-i-set-the-charset-and-collation-for-mysql-tables)
- [MySQL Docs for case sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)
- [MySQL Docs for altering collaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-table.html)

Comment: Ok, Thank you! This answer will be THE answer. Anyway, I managed a workaround to solve my problem in a preventing way. (Making sure the values are always inserted in lowercase and always search in lowercase)