# Case insensitive search using findoneby()

Tags: symfony, case-insensitive

I have one repository called `$colorMaster`

```
$colorMaster->findOneBy(array('name' => 'RED'));
```

It returns no records even though in my database there is records with Value "Red".

when i try to use same code with value 'Red'

```
$colorMaster->findOneBy(array('name' => 'Red'));
```

it returns value.

Is there any way by which we can get case insensitive records from 
symfony `findOneBy();`
so that it can give result using value "RED" also.

Comment: it has been answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458216/symfony2-and-doctrine-how-to-use-findoneby-method-taking-capitals-into-account

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgres database

Comment: And of course postgres is case insensitive.  @Tomasz has the right approach just be aware it might impact your indexes and slow things up.  Search for postgres specific solutions for more info.  But your best bet would be to make your application case insensitive.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Problem is not at Symfony level but at your database level. Some of them are case sensitive and some are not. Yours is case sensitive apparently. To get results, no matter case, try following:

```
     $name = 'REd'; //case doesn't matter
     $colorMaster->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->where('upper(a.name) = upper(:name)')
        ->setParameter('name', $name)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

Comment: A list of available functions in DQL (i.e. upper) can be found in the [Doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, supposedly due to case insensitive character set.

```
$name = 'REd';
$qb   = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

// still returns case insensitive results
$qb->where($qb->expr()->upper('a.name'), $qb->expr()->upper(':name'))
    ->setParameter('name', $name, Type::STRING);

// doctrine syntax error
$name = 'REd';
$qb   = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
$qb->where('BINARY a.name = :name')
    ->setParameter('name', $name, Type::STRING);

// this finally works
$name = 'REd';
$rsm  = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('UserBundle:User', 'u');
$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('SELECT u.* FROM users u WHERE u.name LIKE BINARY :name', $rsm);
$query->setParameters(array('name' => $name));
```